# Facebook comments plugin - Contents disappear when clicked on 'Facebook Comments Plugin' text at bottom

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-comments

I have implemented facebook comments functionality by referring this:
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/09/android-adding-facebook-comments-widget-in-app/

I am facing strange issue. Check text 'Facebook Comments Plugin' at bottom in below screenshot. When I click this text, all contents of webview disappear. Check other screenshot. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image: Before click]

[image: After Click]

Comment: That is just a link to `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/?utm_campaign=social_plugins&utm_medium=offsite_pages&utm_source=comments_plugin`, with `target="_blank"`. Possible that this creates issues inside a webview - but the plugin is not intended for display in a webview in the first place, it is intended to be used on actual websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using following code inside UriWebviewClient

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    if (url.contains("https://developers.facebook.com")) {
       //Do handling or load whatever you want.
    } 
}
```